# Highcharts Issue when applying Boost.js

Tags: csv, highcharts, export

The reason I apply Boost.js is exporting CSV file with big data as well as improving the performance.

I have a problem when using boost and the number of series more than 9. The barchart displays incorrectly. Therefore I try the workaround approach by increasing the the threshold to deactivate the Boost. It's also cause of CSV exporting possibility which I really concern.

Do we have any official update about this problem from the Highcharts Team?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, boost is not available for bar charts (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6602). Solution to this inconvenience is to set type of chart to 'column' and invert it.

```
chart: {
  type: 'column',
  inverted: true
}
```

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.type
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.inverted

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/obx1pbkw/

Comment: Hi d_paul,

Thanks a lot for your info. I'm not only having trouble with barchart but also with other type : scatter, line. Do you have any solution for exporting CSV when we deactivate the Boost?

Comment: What kind of problems? Provide me with a working JSFiddle demo with your CSV data where described problems occur.

Comment: Hi d_paul,  Please take a look this JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ubytofud. I am using the latest version of Boost (5.0.14). In this demo, I find out that seriesThreshold has been increased to 50. The barchart displays incorrectly when the series more than 50 and CSV functionality exports with the header only.  Could you please to help me out?

Comment: As you probably noticed, here you can fixed version of getDataRows() function (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7026). Example:  https://jsfiddle.net/normhxff/.